# Downloading file from multiple sources with HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, http, download

Say that I have a swarm of *slow* servers. Like, as many of them as I want, so that in principle I can offer an immense total amount of bandwidth. However, whenever a user wants do download a file, if I just pick one of my servers as a source for the download, the download is going to take ages.

So I am wondering if solutions exist to make the browser download simultaneously from multiple sources. Please note that each of the sources can be a standard file on a standard http server. If a solution like that actually existed, it would be great, since I could just give the client a small list of my servers, and the client would download simultaneously from as many of them as needed. Is it possible to do such a thing?

I am open to any solution that doesn't require particular permissions from the users (i.e., no extensions or plugins to insall), and that is as cross-browser as possible. I am also not very happy with very small download limits. Javascript is definitely an option.

I thought that I could use javascript to download files in chunks, then merge them into a blob and make the user download the blob. However, this implies that my files can just be as big as a blob, i.e., 500 MB on Chrome, slightly more on several other browsers. So not enough. Are there other solutions? Are there js libraries I can use?

Comment: Is this a purely client side solution you're looking for, or do you own the servers as well? If you do, is it partial ownership, as in GoDaddy or Azure Web, or is it total ownership, like a VM or a server box in your building?

Comment: Yes, I do have a full ownership of all the servers. I have full root access to all of them.

Comment: And the browser doesn't necessarily have to be able to display the file - it can be rerouted immediately to the Downloads folder like what happens when a browser can't display a file?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That would be okay as well!

Comment: @Compynerd255 Do you have something on your mind?

Comment: Kind of. I'll need to do some research to see if what I have works. What I do know is that a lot of this functionality is present in HTTP already.

Comment: @Compynerd255 would you give me an idea on what you were thinking about? Maybe via pm? So that if you don't have time I can start trying that!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

This is a capability that can be set on routers that allows multiple servers to all register to the same IP address - essentially, the router is connected to the public address space with a single address, and all of your servers are connected to it. Then, individual requests can be forwarded by the router to whatever server that has nothing better to do (kept track of in the router), and then forwarded back to the requesting computer.

If you find that things are getting to be too much for your router, you can build another setup like this and put it in a different physical location, registered to the same domain name. Then, your clients will connect to whichever router is closer. To do this quickly in one building, simply have one router connected to each of the major ISPs in your area.

As for large files, HTTP supports [chunked transfer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/648526/All-about-http-chunked-responses), allowing a file or webpage to be downloaded in multiple, smaller chunks. Multiple servers might volunteer to send different chunks, allowing you to paralellize large page download.

Comment: Wait, I do have access to all of them, but I am not able to put them all behind the same ip: the ip is given for each of them, and they all differ..